# Reference outside function var from inside function in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

I'm wondering how to access to an expecific variable in the following code:

**File foo.js**

```
function a(id, callback) {
  //Do things
  if (err) {
    callback(err);
  } else {
    callback(null, result);
  }
}
function b(x, callback) {
  //Do things
  if (err) {
    callback(err);
  } else {
    callback(null, result);
  }
}
```

**File question.js**

```
var id = 1;
var x = 2;
foo.a(id, function(err, result){
  if (err) {
    //Do stuff
  } else {
    foo.b(x, function(err, result){
      if (err) {
        //Do stuff
      } else {
        console.log("Function A: " + result); // I want to log result from foo.a
        console.log("Function B: " + result);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

How can I access inside function foo.b to var result from function foo.a?

**The question is if there is some way to reference the variable without chaging the name. Something like `this.result` or `super.result`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is if there is some way to reference the variable without chaging the name. Something like `this.result` or `super.result`.

No, there's no notation for accessing an identifier from an outer scope (in your case, the `result` parameter in `a`'s callback) that you've shadowed by reusing the identifier name on an error scope (in your case, the `result` parameter on `b`'s callback).

Instead, just give the parameters different names, since your `b` callback closes over the `result` your `a` callback receives:

```
var id = 1;
var x = 2;
foo.a(id, function(err, aresult){ // <=== `aresult` instead of `result`
  if (err) {
    //Do stuff
  } else {
    foo.b(x, function(err, bresult){ // <=== `bresult` instead of `result`
      if (err) {
        //Do stuff
      } else {
        console.log("Function A: " + aresult); // <=== Use them
        console.log("Function B: " + bresult); // <===
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. That is how I "fix" it. But the question is more if there is some way to do the reference.

Comment: @alopez: I don't know what you mean by "do the reference". If you mean can you access `a`'s callback's `result` parameter when you've shadowed it by declaring `result` within `b`'s callback: No, you can't. You've shadowed it by using the same name on an inner scope. There's no scope-specific notation to access it.

Comment: Perfect! That's waht I'm wondering, if there's some notation to access the result from a instead of b. If it is impossible, I'll keep it with the names changed. Thanks!

Comment: @alopez: No worries, glad that helped! Just a side note: You're not accessing these from `a` or `b`, you're accessing them from anonymous callbacks you're passing into `a` and `b`. :-) (You couldn't access them at all from `a` or `b`; they're not in scope.)